# How to validate a cell value in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need a macro that validate a cell value. It needs to check if the value if the value is 7 letters and 6 digits(passwds123456). The letters will always be the same but not the 6 numbers at the end.

I hope I'm clear enough. This is the code I currently have:

```
Private Sub CommandButton15_Click()

        Dim i As Integer

        If Len(Range("H3").Value) <> 13 Then

            MsgBox "ok lenght is not  13"

        End If

        For i = 8 To 13

            If IsNumeric(i) = True Then

               MsgBox "6 last are numbers"

            End If
        Next i
End Sub
```

but this doesn't correctly detect the numbers part.

What am I missing?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.  Please show what you have tried and where you are having a problem.  `I need` statements, as there is no question here, get down voted and closed.

Comment: Check for the number of characters first (If its `len`is 13), then do a `for` loop to check each character and add 1 to variables, then check the value of the variables to see if they match

Comment: Hey Scott I'm new at this. You want me to put code even if it is totally useless? At least Moacir gave something to work on. So I'll put what I have come through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of testing each character to see if it's a number, use `Right` to test the last 6 characters as a single string (using `IsNumeric`):

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

If Len(Range("H3").Value) <> 13 Then
    MsgBox "ok length is not 13"
Else
    If IsNumeric(Right(Range("H3").Value, 6)) = True Then
        MsgBox "6 last are numbers"
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

To expand, if your value in H3 is "passwds123456", `Right(Range("H3").Value, 6)` will return "123456", which then returns True against `IsNumeric`

[image: Example]

**EDIT:**

As @YowE3K pointed out, a number in another notation could pass this test, so a cleaner solution (with a bit more to it) would be to test each of the characters individually:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

Dim i As Integer, flag As Boolean

If Len(Range("H3").Value) <> 13 Then
    MsgBox "ok length is not 13"
Else
    For i = 0 To 5
        If Not IsNumeric(Mid(Range("H3").Value, 8 + i, 1)) = True Then
            flag = True
        End If
    Next i
    If flag = False Then
        MsgBox "6 last are numbers"
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works fine!

Comment: Be careful - that will accept a value of `"passwds1.34e5"`.  You should really test each of the last six characters individually to avoid these situations.

Comment: @YowE3K Good thinking Yow, that didn't even cross my mind. I've edited with another solution to test each character individually.

Comment: FWIW, it isn't even just scientific notation that causes problems - something silly like `"1,2,3,"` and `"1.2,3,"` are still numeric as far as `IsNumeric` is concerned.  (But it won't accept two decimal separators, so `"1.2.3,"` and `"1.2,3."` aren't numeric.  Weird rules!!)